# Differentiability of the operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, normed-spaces

My question is simple. Given finite-dimensional real Banach spaces $V, W$, is the operator norm on $\mathcal{L}(V, W) \setminus \{ 0 \}$ differentiable?

I know the standard Euclidean norm would be, but I don’t know what to do with this.

Comment: Maybe you can use that this norm is equivalent with the usual Euclidean norm. Just an idea. I don't know if this works.

Comment: I am confused : $A \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$, is that right? Also, by $Av$ you mean the dot product $A \cdot v$ of vectors? The problem is that $A$ usually denotes a linear transformation/matrix rather than a vector.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes, by $Av$ I mean the image of a vector $v$ under the linear transformation $A$.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta I considered that, but I think all the equivalence will get me is a continuity statement.

Comment: Yeah all norms are continuous so that' nothing new.

Comment: So you are asking about the differentiability of a map  which takes an operator (a matrix) to a real number, is that right? Do you know the definition of differentiability for maps from one linear space to another? Also, differentiability on $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ is then a typo, is that not?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes. I know what differentiability is. No, it’s not a typo that I excluded $0$ from my domain because I already know that the operator norm would not be differentiable at $0$, as any norm would be non-differentiable there.

Comment: But then $A$ is not an element of $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$, it is an element of the set of matrices/ operators. So the differentiability is to be checked on that space, not on $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$. Ok, just seen the edit, thank you for that.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Good catch, I’ve corrected the notation.

Comment: Yes, now I will attempt the question, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a general answer, it is important to give the definition anyway.

Given the map $ \phi : \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n , \mathbb R^n)$ to $\mathbb R$. We call it differentiable at the point $x$, if there exists a linear functional $\psi : \mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^n , \mathbb R^n) \to \mathbb R$ and a neighbourhood $x \in U$ (in the operator norm) such that for all $x' \in U$:
$$
\phi(x') = \phi(x) + \psi(x' - x) + \epsilon(||x'-x||_{op})
$$

where $\epsilon : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a function satisfying $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\epsilon(h)}{h} = 0$.

---

The map $\phi(A) = \max_{|v| = 1} |Av| = \|A\|_{op}$ , on the given normed vector spaces , is *Lipschitz*. The reason for this is obviously the triangle inequality $$ 
\bigg|\|A\|_{op} - \|B\|_{op}\bigg| \leq \|A-B\|_{op} \implies |\phi(A) - \phi(B)| \leq \|A-B\|_{op}
$$

It is well known by Rademacher's theorem that any such map is differentiable almost everywhere. So you do get differentiability at a lot of points. But no, not everywhere.

---

Of course not, because let $I$ be the identity linear transformation on $\mathbb R^n$. We claim $\phi$ is not differentiable at $I$. Think of $I$ as a diagonal matrix of ones.

Suppose $\phi$ is differentiable at $I$, say with the neighbourhood $U$ around $I$ given by differentiability, then consider the map (for small enough $\epsilon$ )$\xi : (-\epsilon , \epsilon) \to \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n)$ defined as follows : let $C$ be a linear  transformation sending $w \to w$ (for $0 \neq w$) and everything else to zero, and now define $\xi(t) = I + tC$ with $\epsilon$ small enough that $\xi(t) \in U$ for all $t \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

Think of $C$ as a matrix of zeros except it has a $1$ at one point in the diagonal. Then $tC$ is that same matrix with $1$ replaced by $t$.

It is easy to see that $\xi$ is differentiable, I leave you to see that. Now, by the chain rule, $\phi \circ \xi : (-\epsilon , \epsilon) \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, in the usual sense.

But what is this map? It is nothing but $||I+tC||_{op}$.

Now we understand the operators $I+tC$. For $t$ negative, this is a matrix with ones on the diagonal , except $1+t < 1$ at one position. The maximum norm of this matrix is $1$, easily enough.

Now, for $t$ positive, we'd have a $1+t > 1$ in that position, which gives the maximum norm as $1+t$.

Finally, the description :
$$
\phi \circ \xi(t) = \begin{cases}
1 & t \leq 0 \\
1+t & t > 0
\end{cases}
$$

is clearly that of a non-differentiable function. It follows that $\phi$ is not differentiable at $I$.

You can probably generalize this in some way to other points.

Comment: Thanks! I like this, and I think I have an idea for how to generalize it. I’ll try to write it up today.

Comment: You are welcome! Also try to find points of differentiability, and see if they cover everything except a set of "measure zero" in $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ in the finite dimensional case.

Comment: It seems that we have two possibilities: (1) There exist two linearly independent unit vectors $v, w$ such that $|Av| = |Aw| = \| A \|$, in which case something like your argument about $I$ applies to show non-differentiability at $A$, or (2) there exists only one (up to sign) unit vector which maximizes $|Av|$, in which case we should have differentiability at $A$. I haven’t put pencil to paper on the latter yet, though.

Comment: Sure, take your time

Answer (score 2):

Consider $V=W=\mathbb R^n$ with $\|\cdot\|$ as the spectral norm on matrices (induced by the 2-norm on vectors). If $\|\cdot\|$ is differentiable, then for any $A,B$, the one-sided directional derivatives
$$\nabla_B\|A\|=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\|A+hB\|-\|A\|}{h}$$
should satisfy $\nabla_B\|A\|=-\nabla_{-B}\|A\|$.
However, take $A=I$ and $B=\operatorname{diag}(1,0,\dots,0)$, and we have $\nabla_B\|A\|=1$ but $\nabla_{-B}\|A\|=0$.